# Parsing JSON with AFNetworking give results with round brackets

Tags: xcode, json, parsing, afnetworking

Here is the simplified JSON file, I need to download it from a net service and parse results in a table!

**EDIT:** I provide now more precise code, cleaned and formatted by online tool:

```
{
  "main": [
    {
      "id": 0, <--- float value
      "type": "type0", <--- STRING value
      "valueA": {
        "valueA1": 1, <--- float value
        "valueA2": 2, <--- float value
        "valueA3": 3  <--- float value
      },
      "valueB": {
        "valueB1": 1, <--- float value
        "valueB2": 2  <--- float value
      },
      "valueC": [
        {
          "valueC1": "string0C1", <--- STRING value
          "valueC2": 2, <--- float value
          "valueC3": 3, <--- float value
        }
      ]
    },
```

FORMATTED by online tool jsonviewer.stack.hu:

[image]

I need to parse it with AFJSONRequestOperation, and I write this code:

```
NSMutableArray *main = [JSON objectForKey:@"main"];
arrayID = [main valueForKey:@"id"];
arrayType = [main valueForKey:@"type"];

NSMutableArray *arrayValueC = [main valueForKey:@"valueC"];
NSMutableString *stringC1 = [arrayValueC valueForKey:@"valueC1"]; 

// I CANT USE objectForKey, XCode give an exception -[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

NSLog(@"id: %@",arrayID);
NSLog(@"type: %@",arrayType);
NSLog(@"string: %@",stringC1);
```

When I parse, I get this results from NSLog:

```
id: (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9
)

type: (
    type0,
    type1,
    type2,
    type3,
    type4,
    type5,
    type6,
    type7,
    type8,
    type9
)

string: (
        (
        "string0C1"
    ),
        (
        "string2C1"
    ),
        (
        "string2C1"
    ),
        (
        "string3C1"
    ),
        (
        "string4C1"
    ),
        (
        "string5C1"
    ),
        (
        "string6C1"
    ),
        (
        "string7C1"
    ),
        (
        "string8C1"
    ),
        (
        "string9C1"
    )
)
```

As u can see its all perfect, I can extrapolate every value of ID (float) and TYPE (string), but I hate the round brackets in every object of the valueC1 string: how can I get the clean valueC1 without brackets and quotation marks? Please if u can provide some code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `valueForKey:`. Use `objectForKey:` instead. This is probably the major problem. But once you use it, you might run into new problem:

The following contains a problem that will manifest itself when `arrayValueA` is accessed the first time:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayValueA = [arrayMain objectForKey:@"valueA"];
```

The element stored at `valueA` is an object i.e. a dictionary and not an array.

Finally, your *simplified* JSON is invalid anyway. Several values are missing double quotes, e.g.:

```
"id": id0
```

should be:

```
"id": "id0"
```

You better shows the real JSON data and the real code.

**Update:**

You should be able to access the JSON data with the following code:

```
NSArray *main = [JSON objectForKey:@"main"];
NSDictionary* main0 = [main objectAtIndex:0];
arrayID = [main0 objectForKey:@"id"];
arrayType = [main0 objectForKey:@"type"];

NSArray *arrayValueC = [main objectForKey:@"valueC"];
NSDictionary *elem0 = [arrayValueC objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *stringC1 = [arrayValueC objectForKey:@"valueC1"]; 

NSLog(@"id: %@",arrayID);
NSLog(@"type: %@",arrayType);
NSLog(@"string: %@",stringC1);
```

Comment: Thanks Codo, but its not my JSON, I need to download it from the net and parse; I've formatted it with online tool, and these are results. I have now edited my question to provide more precise and cleaner code: objectForKey give me an exception. Please can u help me more?

Comment: @Huxley: Be grateful for the exception. They tell you where you have casted an object to the wrong type. Currently, your using *NSMutableDictionary*, *NSMutableArray* and *NSMutableString* when in fact the objects are *NSDictionary*, *NSArray* and *NSString* instances.

Comment: Im sorry, and I'm grateful for the exception. But even using NSDictionary, NSArray and NSString in the place of NSMutable... I get the same error: unrecognized selector. And, with all combinations of array and dictionary, for cycle and key values, I can't actually see brackets and quotation marks disappearing from the "valueC1" strings. Maybe I need some code to recognize precise issue.

Comment: Your JSON data contains several arrays. However, your code seems to want to skip them. Instead of retrieving an array element at a given index (`objectAtIndex:`), it treats the array as if it was a dictionary contained in the array (`objectForKey:`). I've updated my answer and added some code.

Comment: Ok, Codo, now your code is Ok, i forgot some NSDictionary. I have added also a 'for (int i=0; i < [main count]; i++)' cycle after NSArray *main to retrieve ALL the values of stringC1 (with your code I get only LAST value) and now I havent bracket and quotation marks: thank you very much!